# DateTime.TryParse() fails in Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7

`DateTime.TryParse` fails in Windows 7, when we change the regional settings to Italian.I even tried `TryParseExact` but with no luck. Does anybody have any idea on this or came across this type of scenario?

Code is some thing like this:

```
string[] formats = {"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", "M/d/yyyy hh tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"}; 
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(cb.Text, formats, CultureInfo.InVariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AllowLeadingWhite, out date_and_time))
```

but it returns false.

or

Even tried:

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(cb.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,out date_and_time) == true)`
```

cb.Text is a String which contains the DateTime in string representation.

Comment: An example of the code you are using would be helpful.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail as to how it fails?

Comment: Give example of the date you are trying to parse and your code to parse it. I have used Win7 for a long time now and never have issue with DateTime parsing. I suspect is that your date text is in one culture format/custom format and you are trying to parse it using default cultureinfo that cant parse the date text

Comment: @Sunil: and what does you input look like? What's the contents of cb.Text?

Comment: @Sunil, please add the code to the sample (with formatting). More readable for the rest of us.

Comment: What .Net version are you using?

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling it with a neutral CultureInfo?

Like this

```
DateTime parsed;

if(DateTime.TryParse("2010-03-09", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsed))
    Console.WriteLine(parsed)
```

Or for TryParseExact

```
DateTime.TryParseExact("2010-03-09", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsed)
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more information about how it fails? Ideally a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

In Italian the time separator token is resolved to . rather than :

Try escaping the time separator token in single quotes for example:

```
"M/d/yyyy h':'mm':'ss tt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting [Thread Culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture.aspx) to `Italian Culture` using [CreateSpecificCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.createspecificculture.aspx) method.

See list of cultures [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/).